# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Wont Boot

Tags: boot, 16.04

When I boot up ubuntu 16.04 it hangs at
`/ded/sdal: clean, 61220/4825088 files, 635469 19287040 blocks` what do I do?

I'm using a Toshiba nb200-13e.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 is EoL and off-topic here.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: I mean that 16.10 is obsolete, not supported and questions about it are off-topic at this site. Install a supported release.

Comment: this is ask ubuntu so i expect help for my error

Comment: and i cant cause i have 32 bit not 64

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: bruh its literally the latest 32x version of ubuntu whatdo u expect me to do

Comment: There is supported Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit and also Xubuntu and Lubuntu 32-bit available 18.04 LTS and 19.10.

Comment: my bad its actually 16.04

Comment: Then more details are needed. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: what do you mean all it does is hang on /ded/sdal: clean, 61220/4825088 files, 635469 19287040 blocks

Comment: that is related but not the same

Comment: I gave a link to a question with multiple solutions of this type of issues. It is impossible to tell what is the problem with no information at all.

Comment: well first of all i used the network installer

Comment: [edit] your question and add details about your hardware, what you did and what happened.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling seems to work so thats it